# Any other approach instead of Properties file?

Tags: java, properties, build

I have an legacy code base , which is built by using ant. I can see lot’s of properties file been used throughout the project, which gives deployment url and other things.

I certainly hate this approach. By any chance, we can remove these properties file and inject these values to Java classes at run time?

And I see most of the properties files are used in build.xml. Does other build tool handles these situation in ease?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might use XML files, you might use a database, or you might choose some other external file format. What part of properties files do you find so objectionable?

Comment: Most of the properties file gives the user location. Like `location=/users/batman/something.jar`. Now clearly, this wont work on others system. I'm totally worried about these things.

Comment: Of course that will work on other systems, once you modify the properties file. That's the advantage of not embedding your directory structure in code.